# Get Current User ASP.NET Visual Studio 2013 Preview ClaimsPrinciple

Tags: asp.net, webforms, claims-based-identity, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get the current user in a web forms project using the new Visual Studio 2013 Preview for Web. I'm able to get the username using Page.User, but trying to get the user id is where I'm stuck. It's using this new Identity Model thing they've come out with.

This is what I've got:

```
//Gets the correct username
string uname = User.Identity.Name;
//Returns a null object
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser user = IdentityConfig.Users.Find(uname);
//What I hope to call to add a user to a role
IdentityConfig.Roles.AddUserToRole("NPO", user.Id);
```

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Sorry, yes. There's sample code there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Default Membership that come's with the ASP.NET WebForms Template you should do something like this to retrieve the user:

```
if (this.User != null && this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

The new model you are talking about is `ClaimsPrincipal`. The unique difference is this [Claims Based Secury](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/08/01/Leveraging-Claims-Based-Security-in-ASPNET-45.aspx), that is completly compatible with the older versions but more powerfull.

EDIT:

To add an user to some `Role` programaticaly you should do this, passing the user name and the role name:

```
if (this.User != null && this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "Role Name");    
}
```

Using the new Claim Based Security

```
if (this.User != null && this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  ClaimsPrincipal cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;

  GenericIdentity genericIdentity;
  ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity;
  Claim claim;

  genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(userName, "Custom Claims Principal");

  claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(genericIdentity);

  claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Role Name");
  claimsIdentity.AddClaim(claim);

  cp.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
}
```

Comment: That's great, I'm glad to know what it's called now. The only thing is how do I add a user to a role? The Roles.AddUserToRole function requires the ID. I can't seem to find that.

Comment: Ok...then, how do I get all roles a user is associated with? Say if I wanted to restrict access to a folder or file based off of what role they belong to?

Comment: Take a look here for more infor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx

Comment: I can't just use the role class, though, because RoleManager is disabled by default, right?

Answer (score 2):

The user id is stored in the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier claim by default.  We provided an extension method as well that lives in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity so you can simply call Page.User.Identity.GetUserId(), instead of fetching the user just to get out the id.

Comment: Definately doesnt work for me. I have a Claims Identity but the GetUserId() returns null. The primary key on the Users tables is a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Just a post for people who find this today this is now very easy to accomplish

```
ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
ApplicationSignInManager signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
ApplicationUser user = signinManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync("username").Result;
```

At this point you have access to everything Id, Email, Phone number, Even the Hashed version of the user password.